# xhr запросы в цикле

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

почему при выполнении данного цикла я получаю результат только последнего xhr запроса?как исправить?

```
for(var i = 0;i<urls.length;i++)
                    {
                        xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr1.open("GET", urls[i], true);
        xhr1.send(null);
            xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr1.readyState == 4) 
            { 
        console.log(xhr1.status);
                if (xhr1.responseText) 
                {
                    var dat = xhr1.responseText;
                    var str  = dat.substring(dat.indexOf('filehd')+9,dat.indexOf('.mp4',dat.indexOf('filehd'))+4);
                    $('#wrapper').append(str+'\n');
                }
            }
            }
                    }
```

Comment: это кросс доменные  запросы они должны быть асинхронными, синхронные хром не пропускает, разве xhr1.onreadystatechange = function()... не ждет пока выполнится запрос?
..

Comment: Потому что Ваши запросы, являясь `асинхронными`, выполняются параллельно, javascript не ждёт окончания исполнения запроса. Можно делать `синхронные` запросы. Для этого заменить второй параметр в функции `xhr1.open` с `true` на `false`: `xhr1.open("GET", urls[i], false);` `Но синхронные запросы считаются плохой практикой и в современных браузерах могут не работать в главном потоке.` Так же есть варианты с асинхронными запросами, но слишком сложные для комментария.

Comment: `onreadystatechange` - это же callback. Он ничего не ждёт по определению. Он вызывается браузером, когда тот считает нужным.

Comment: можете написать как сделать чтобы каждый запрос ждал завершения загрузки, а то получается что  я получаю результат только последнего а их может быть 50+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы с каждой итерацией переписываете `xhr1`.
Получается что ещё ничего не успело загрузится, а цикл затёр прошлые инстансы `XMLHttpRequest`, остался последний.

---

Лучше юзайте [`fetch`](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch):

```
['http://uri1.net', 'http://uri2.org'].forEach(uri => {
  fetch(uri)
    .then(r => r.text()) // Получаем ответ как текст
    .then(data => {
      // Работа с ответом тут через data
    })
});
```

Comment: работает, спасибо за решение

Comment: @Bond, пожалуйста, спасибо тут выражают в плюсах и, если ответ помог, принятием ответа (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: еще 1 вопрос: в расширении генерируется popup.html с помощью js как мне эту результирующую страницу открыть в новой вкладке(програмно) без повторной генерации страницы

Comment: @Bond, открытие новых вкладок/окон - деликатная тема. Обычно решается через `windw.open('http://google.com/', '_blank');`, но часто режется это.

Comment: я вывожу информацию $('#wrapper').append(str+'\n'); что находится на popup.html(скрипты выполняются там же) , как мне этот враппер допустим засунуть в локальный html файл который я буду открывать после нажатия на иконку расширения

Comment: Работать с ФС JS не может (и слава Мне). Хотя поговаривают что великими колдунствами можно из-под хрома что-то сделать. Но лучше используйте [хранилища](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) для этого.

Comment: тоесть я не могу открыть с помощью расширения новую вкладку с информацией которая получена с помощью js во вкладке где я запустил расширение?

Comment: Через расширение - можно. Необходимо разрешение `tabs` и открываем `chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html#asWindow')});`. Там проверяем - если якорь `asWindow` в наличии - выводим сохранённые в хранилище данные.